# Dialog box in VS code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to create the dialog/modal window in vs code. How to create it?
I have tried using web view but not got successes.
Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Why not use the showInformationMessage(), showWarningMessage() or showErrorMessage() methods?

Comment: I want to implement Wizard like feature in my extension. So on command , I need to show the dialog box, which will show multi-step html form  using webview.

Comment: I don't understand why you want the dialog box. Isn't it enough with the webview? If the wizard only has a few questions, perhaps even a sequence of QuickPicks and InputBoxes might be enough.

Comment: While creating new file specific to my extension, I want dialogbox.QuickPicks and InputBoxes are not enough

Comment: Why doesn't a webview work?

Comment: it doesn't open like modal window.Could you plea tell me how to do that?

Comment: Then we're back at the question why you want to show it like a modal. That blocks the user from working with other things.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your question with explanation of why you want a modal and why you think that a webview doesn't work.

Comment: See the screenshot in question. I want to implement the dialog+wizard like this. It's from eclipse. When I am creating my project/file user should not do any other thing.

Comment: Telerik has a [similar wizard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TelerikInc.aspnetcoretemplatewizard). They use a webview: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telerik/vscode-extensions-public-resources/main/images/Core_VSCode_Create_a_project_V2.0.0.png

Comment: Problem is not  creating wizard. Problem is to show this wizard as dialog box.

Comment: You cannot do that. Look at Telerik; they don't show it as a dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to show more than a simple input or yes/no dialog in VS Code. This is an IDE focused on editing code, not creating entire workflows.

Hence the only way to accomplish a wizard like style is to implement that yourself using a webview (as mentioned a few times in the comments). However, webviews are normal tabs, not modal dialogs, which is all what you can get.

On the other hand, it's not really a limitation if the user can switch to other places in VS Code while running your wizard. The webview is in itself modal and you cannot do anything else in that webview while the wizard is running.

And finally: modal dialogs are considered problematic UI, as they force the user into some special mode, which is often counter productive. Which means, they should be used with great care.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project on GitHub that solves this problem. I have used it already and it works: https://github.com/jasongin/vscode-webview-dialog